# how to create the different errors (404,500,419) intentionally? Lavravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to redirect me to my different blade pages located in `resources\views\errors`
how to create the different error cases

- 404
- 402
- 419
- 500
  to test the designs of my different pages and see if it works.

I tried `abort("404");` or `abort("419");` but they sent me to `404.blade.php`.

how to simulate the other errors?

Your help will be very useful to me.

Comment: Your quotes are all messed up, but that just may be a bad copy issue. [abort()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-abort) should show the correct blade, but check your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to make sure you're not changing the view at all

Comment: I corrected the question. Alright I'm off to check `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `abort()` function takes an integer, not a string. From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#http-exceptions):

> Some exceptions describe HTTP error codes from the server. For example, this may be a "page not found" error (404), an "unauthorized error" (401) or even a developer generated 500 error. In order to generate such a response from anywhere in your application, you may use the abort helper:

```php
abort(404); // instead of abort("404");
```

The [API-reference](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/%5BGlobal_Namespace%5D.html#function_abort) shows that the first parameter should be an integer.

Comment: It seems to be converting the string to an int, at least with Laravel 9.